# ArrayList on model class

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, arraylist, model

I was just wondering if there is any possibility to create a list or ArrayList on Model class.

Following the data below, as you can see there is ConditionList to pass on Model class.

```
    {
    "Id": 30,
    "FirstName": "Lilly",
    "LastName": "Fowler",
    "KnownName": "Lills",
    "GenderId": 14,
    "DateOfBirth": "2009-03-18T00:00:00",
    "**ConditionList**": [{
        "Child_ConditionId": 11,
        "Name": "Bee Sting Allergy",
        "Treatment": "phone me and softly put the bee sting cream on it and smooth it down.The cream will be in her bag",
        "DoctorName": null,
        "DoctorContact": null,
        "MedicationDescription": null
    }],
    "CreatedOn": "2015-05-30T19:44:13.2",
    "UpdatedOn": "2015-06-04T19:29:01.303",
    "ProfileImage": "http://mobile.aimy.co.nz:80/Media/mum_cropped_4fe98f04-f772-4ac0-ba51-d99fbd119e4b.jpeg"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SerializeName("**ConditionList**") private List<ConditionList> conditionList;
```

Since you are not allowed to use such symbol in Java variable, you should use serializing name that is chipped with `Gson`

Comment: Getting erro on <ConditionList> it should be passed as String. But any away Thanks.

@SerializeName("**ConditionList**") private List<ConditionList>conditionList;